# In an SQL statement, how do you select all elements that are NOT a certain condition?

Tags: java, sql, named-query

I'm sorry I formulated the question so badly--I'm new to programming.

What I'm doing is, I'm using Java @NamedQuery in a little Library manager application. I have the entity class Book with attributes bookid, title, author, etc. and Bookstaken with attributes id, clientid, bookid, datetaken. So Bookstaken.bookid is the foreign key that refers to Book.bookid. Bookstaken contains all the books that have been taken, and Book contains all the books that the library owns (but does not necessarily have at the moment).

I have fetched all Books that have been *taken* with this Named Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Taken", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b, Bookstaken t WHERE b = t.bookid")
```

But now I want to make a Named Query called "Not taken" which will retrieve all books that have... you know, not been taken. So essentially the complementary group of the query "Taken".

I have tried this:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Not taken", query = "SELECT b FROM Book b, Bookstaken t WHERE b <> t.bookid")
```

(and I've tried replacing <> with !=)

But that statement is giving the entire group of Books, every single one of them, and giving that exact group multiple times. Why is this happening? I was never talented at SQL... And how can I fix it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you have to realize that what you have here is not SQL, but JPQL. These are two different languages.

Second, your query shows that you have a misconception. The BookTaken entity shouldn't have a bookid field. It should have a toOne association with Book, and thus a field of type Book.

Finally, the query you have is not correct. What you want is all the books for which there doesn't exist any BookTaken entity referencing this book:

```
select b from Book b where not exists (
    select bt.id from BookTaken bt where bt.bookid = b.id)
```

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should be certain of what you are comparing. In:

```
@NamedQuery(... "SELECT b FROM Book b, Bookstaken t WHERE b <> t.bookid")
```

You are comparing a `Book` with an id (`Bookstaken.bookid`). The latter probably is an `Integer`, thus always different from a `Book`.

By that rationale, you should use: `"SELECT b FROM Book b, Bookstaken t WHERE b.bookid != t.bookid"`, as `b != t.bookid` would return `true` for all elements.

But that would probably not be just what you want. As rightfully pointed out in the comments, the above would result in a cartesian product. What you want is more along the lines of an SQL `JOIN`, a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, to be more specific.

As in JPQL, `LEFT JOIN` has actually the semantics of SQL's `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, you could just use, then:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Not taken", query = 
"SELECT b FROM Book b LEFT JOIN Bookstaken t ON b.bookid = t.bookid "+
"WHERE t.bookid IS NULL")
```

Comment: That query won't return the desired results. It creates a cross join (cartesian product) between the two entities, and keeps all the rows where the two bookids don't match. It thus selects all books, several times.

Comment: Would not this result in a cartesian product? I'm not familiarized with @NamedQuery in plain sql the right way would be a left join with is null. Like `SELECT b.* FROM Book b left join Bookstaken t on  b.bookid = t.bookid WHERE t.bookid is null`. I'm just curious.

Comment: You guys are correct. I must admit at first I just focused in the operator, rather than the end result the OP needed. I just fixed so, for future readers, it may be of some help, though I think the `EXISTS` solution is simpler. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching the query the wrong way.  You're telling the database that you want all pairs of rows from `Book` and `Bookstaken` where the `Bookstaken` doesn't match the `Book`.  As you can imagine, there are lots of pairs of rows that don't match, so you're getting lots of rows, which is not what you want.

What you really want is to select all rows in `Book` that don't have a corresponding rown in `Bookstaken`.  You can do this with `SELECT b from Book WHERE NOT EXISTS( SELECT * from Bookstaken t WHERE t.bookid = b.bookid )`.

Or you can use a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` to join `Book`s to their matching `Bookstaken`s but leave in the result set any `Books` that don't have a corresponding `Bookstaken`, and then use `WHERE t.bookid = NULL` to get only the ones without a corresponding `Bookstaken`.